# how to add 2 list in nested listview in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin froms. i need to bind 2 list in one listview.i am getting dataset from webservice(Total 3 datatables). I Have tried implementing nested listview i.e listview inside listview. i am giving them the name but when i am trying to access the inner listview code behind is not picking up(I know the reason tho). i have researched but i didnt got any relevant article to go through. here is what i have implemented. Basically, i am trying to build a survey/test app.

```
IEnumerable<StartParticularSurvey> _questionList;
IEnumerable<StartParticularSurvey> _answerList;

var response = e.Result.ToString();
var result = StartParticularSurvey.FromJson(response);
            if (result[0][0].bit_HasError == true)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new UserSurveyList());
                    DisplayAlert("Alert!", result[0][0].vchar_ErrorMsg, "Ok");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var questionDataset = result[1][0]; //trying to get Table2 in questionDataset
                    var answerDataset = result[2][0]; //trying to get Table3 in answerDataset
                    _questionList = questionDataset as IEnumerable<StartParticularSurvey>;
                    _answerList = answerDataset as IEnumerable<StartParticularSurvey>;
                    lvSurveyQuestion.ItemsSource = _questionList;
                    lvSurveyAnswer.itemSource = _answerList; //Here is where the .cs is not picking up and i know why.
                });
            }
```

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSurveyQuestion">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{binding data here}"/>
                                <ListView x:Name="lvSurveyAnswer">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{binding data here}"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{binding data here}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Model:

```
namespace IVSConnectMobile.Model
{
    public partial class StartParticularSurvey
    {
        [JsonProperty("bit_HasError", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? bit_HasError { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vchar_ErrorMsg", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string vchar_ErrorMsg { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("int_SurveyQuestionID", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? int_SurveyQuestionID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vchar_Description", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string vchar_Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vchar_Instruction")]
        public string vchar_Instruction { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("int_AnswerType", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? int_AnswerType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vchar_Option", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string vchar_Option { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class StartParticularSurvey
    {
        public static List<List<StartParticularSurvey>> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<StartParticularSurvey>>>(json, IVSConnectMobile.Model.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this List<List<StartParticularSurvey>> self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, IVSConnectMobile.Model.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

[This Image is the result that i am getting after serializing the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XosF.png)

Any other suggestion are welcome

[This is a sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKIcH.png)

**EDIT**

I created 2 Model

```
 public class SurveyAnswerList
    {
        public int int_AnswerType { get; set; }
        public string vchar_Option { get; set; }
    }

public class SurveyQuestionList : List<SurveyAnswerList>
    {
        public string vchar_Description { get; set; }

        public SurveyQuestionList(string description)
        {
            vchar_Description = description;
        }
    }
```

In code behind

```
public List<Model.SurveyQuestionList> _list { get; set; }

_list = new List<Model.SurveyQuestionList>();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result[1].Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < result[2].Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (result[1][i].int_SurveyQuestionID == result[2][j].int_SurveyQuestionID)
                            {
                                _list = new List<SurveyQuestionList>{
                                    new SurveyQuestionList(result[1][i].vchar_Description){
                                        new SurveyAnswerList{ vchar_Option = result[2][j].vchar_Option }
                                    }
                                };
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    lvSurvey.ItemsSource = _list;
                });
```

XAML:

```
             <ListView x:Name="lvSurvey"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding vchar_Description}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding vchar_Option}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: ListView inside Listview is not recommended. Please avoid use of it.

Comment: so how do i make a survey question. question's and answer both are coming as a list. can you suggest me something

Comment: Use DataTemplate instead of Inner ListView.

Comment: but then how do i bind 2 lists in one listview

Comment: What kind of UI is that? Have you any sample?

Comment: no. its just a normal ui. question and answer

Comment: Then you can make one DataTemplate with Five lables. First for question and remaining will be Options. And used in ListView.

Comment: Just refer "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector" this document. You might get idea about this.

Comment: Also you can use Grouping in Listview.

Comment: hi, i tried grouping 2 list the whole day i am referring this article [link]https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/ . but as you can see from my above model i only have a single list and from the image that i have attached you can see that there are 3 list(3 datatables coming) from webservice all at once and i have separated manually. can you please help

Comment: Can you post your Grouping code?

Comment: i have edited. Please check

Comment: This shows me the output but the only thing is that only one Question and Answer is coming and i know why. can you help me here

Comment: i was thinking of using Grid. i Would just like to know how do i repeat the gridview in order to fit all the data

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSurvey"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True">
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding vchar_Description}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>


            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding vchar_Option}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Try this code.

Comment: What do you link about grid?. Can that help me out

Comment: In grid How will you do that?

Comment: i have not implemented yet i was just thinking

Comment: I think using Grid not possible to resolve this Issue.

Comment: thanks for the help. i think i will drop the idea of displaying it in list and go with one question at a time

Comment: Okay. As you wish.